# Could not reset the drag and drop images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I would like to  reset the drag and drop images to their respective places after a drag and drop action has performed.

Here is my code:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
});
$("#draggable2").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
});
$("#droppable").droppable({
});
$("#btnReset").click(function() {
    $("#draggable, #draggable2").animate({
        "top": $("#draggable").data("top"),
        "top": $("#draggable").data("top")
    });
});
$("#draggable").data("top", $("#draggable").position().top).data("top",      $("#draggable").position().top);
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1xnmtyqs/20/)

Here is a working [Example](http://bengal.missouri.edu/~glgqk3/Graber_Phd_Portfolio/documents/Simple_drag_n_drop.html)

Comment: how do you mean "to their respective places"

Comment: @Alexandros      Something like this http://bengal.missouri.edu/~glgqk3/Graber_Phd_Portfolio/documents/Simple_drag_n_drop.html

Comment: i dont know how you see it (browser etc?) but the only difference from the "working example" is that in the example it changes opacity permanently